# Node.js - Node Mailer: Username and Password not accepted

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I am using nodemailer to send token to email (gmail smtp) but I'm getting this error:**

```
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v185sm51735194pfb.14 - gsmtp
```

Im using seperate file to secure my email address and password which is secret.js below is my code.

```js
module.exports = {
    auth:{
        user: 'myrealemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'myrealpassword',
    }
}
```

below is the code for user.js

```js
var User = require('../models/user');
var secret = require('../secret/secret');

 function(rand, callback){
                User.findOne({'email':req.body.email}, (err, user) => {
                    if(!user){
                        req.flash('error', 'No account exist or email is invalid');
                        return res.redirect('/forgot');
                    }
                    // Set random token 
                    user.passwordResetToken = rand;
                    user.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 60*60*1000;

                    user.save((err) => {
                        callback(err, rand, user)
                    });
                })
            },
            //sending token to users email
            function(rand, user, callback){
                var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: 'Gmail',
                    auth: {
                        user: secret.auth.user,
                        pass: secret.auth.pass
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Include host and port number- example for gmail- host: "smtp.gmail.com",port: 587

Answer (score 0):

Enable this security option in gmail to make it work. [Allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1)

Comment: update? does it work?

Comment: Gmail is not working for me but yahoo does. So I just used yahoo instead of Gmail as stated in doc in nodemailer - npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer#im-having-issues-with-gmail

Comment: you have to turn on the less secure apps in gmail or it won't work